# Windows service not running. Error 1053

Tags: c#, service

I m trying to run my windows service but it is giving error 1053: "timed out"
The error 1053 should pop up in case the start up method fails to respond in 30 seconds but in this case the OnStart method is not even reached. I tried debugging it but it is not helping as i don't even reach the actual code and the error message pops up before that. Can any one help in this case?

Comment: Well, what does your `Main` entry-point look like? Are there any constructors or other bits of code that do things? Have you added logging to see what it is doing?

Comment: Did you check the event log? The service could be not installed correctly or the account assigned to it might not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Did you marked the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in the `Exceptions` window (part of Debug menu)? If you do that, you'll see where your code stops and has a problem.

Comment: Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller shows this in the event log.

Comment: @MarcGravell main method is just
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
      ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
   { 
    new FileProc() 
   };
      ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

Comment: @user2038650 any other code happening before OnStart? constructors, type initializers, perhaps?

Comment: @MarcGravell initialize component thats it.. nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was trying to install a service at remote desktop and erring

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I was able to fix this issue by installing the targeted dotnet framework
(sometime remote servers on lower framework and we build the service using latest framework).

So my finding is that in these cases you need to check few things:

- install proper dependencies
- all dlls are with targeted framework
- Main static method present in servivce.cs

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Windows Services development and **Faced Same Issue**

I tried everything that was given in this link [this link](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/) and
in [this link](https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/windows-could-not-start-the-service-on-local-computer-error-1053.html) but still I was not able to fix issue!

Then I tried some other small things on my own and I found 2 things in my solution

1. **Startup Object Not Set in solution properties**

   - for this, right click -> windowsServiceProject -> click properties -> in there will be left menu in it click on ->Application ->Check "Startup Object" -> If its "empty" ? then click and select project/Service Name.Program (in my case the main method is in program.cs so..)
     and if it's selected and is ok then... there can be an error in your code see point number 2
2. **Error In Our Service Code**

   - For this try to simply run the project with Pressing "Start".
   - If there are any exception or error Like: null pointer or, there were some wrong or missing path or anything that generates exception on running because of developer's mistake then it will show a thrown error and you will able to solve it EG:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hywiJ.png)
   - or if the code is ok then it will show like this:
     a dialog box "Windows Service can not be debugged you have to install it
     first then and then it will be able to run" (if this dialog shows it's ok normal behaviour if showing any exception then fix that thing and rebuild you will be able to start the service)